# Javascript makes my website not scrollable on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, skrollr

I'm currently experimenting with the Twitter Bootstrap framework and using the Skrollr plugin for awesome parallax effects. But I'm having a problem with scrolling when looking my website on tablet and smartphone.
I've noticed that there's a small piece of javascript code that causes the website not to be scrollable on mobile devices.

```
    var s = skrollr.init({
        edgeStrategy: 'set',
        easing: {
            WTF: Math.random,
            inverted: function(p) {
                return 1-p;
            }
        }
    });
```

When I remove this tiny piece of code, the website becomes suddenly scrollable but causes the different parallax plates to disappear. Does anyone have this problem as well and do you have a solution for this problem.

SOLUTION: (tnx for the comments and help)

```
        if (document.createTouch) {
    //mobile code
} else {
    var s = skrollr.init({
            edgeStrategy: 'set',
            easing: {
                WTF: Math.random,
                inverted: function(p) {
                    return 1-p;
                }
            }
        });
}
```